# How to re-scale the inputs for forward-propagation and backpropagation in the drop out?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, dropout

Assume $p$ is the keep probability for drop out, for the forward-propagation, we do the scaling for the inputs as $A_r = A/p$.
In the backpropagation, as many other people said ([dropout: forward prop VS back prop in machine learning Neural Network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219236/dropout-forward-prop-vs-back-prop-in-machine-learning-neural-network)),  we should obtain the gradient as $dA = dA_r/p$. However, in my view, it should be $dA = dA_r * p$. Is it correct?